# Can we prove that all possible symmetries of a system were found?

Tags: symmetry, noethers-theorem

I am thinking something which could be similar as Gödel's works - but not with axioms of logical systems, but with symmetries of (theoretical) physical systems.

Such a proof would mean, that adding any new symmetry, would either contradict the others, or it could be derived from them.

I think, having such a proof would mean, that a theory is "ready". For example, I think the Newtonian Mechanics and the SR are probably "ready" in this sense, but I can't proove it.

Furthermore, applying the Noether theorem, it would also mean, that all conserved quantities of a theory were already found.

Comment: Just throwing it out there: If you could prove you had a particular number of D.O.F, you could find a maximal number of independent generators of a global continuous symmetry. The same cannot be said for global discrete symmetries, and perhaps also not for gauge symmetries.

Comment: If you like this question you may also enjoy reading [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/8626/2451) Phys.SE post.