# Conserved Quantities And Lagrangian Mechanics

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, conservation-laws, symmetry, noethers-theorem, integrable-systems

By Noether's Theorem we know that any conserved quantity can be associated with a continuous symmetry. I was reading Kepler's Problem and I saw that there can be conserved quantities like *Laplace-Runge-Lenz* vector which might not be obvious to figure out. So my questions are,

1. Are there any techniques to find **all** of the conserved quantities?
2. How many conserved quantities can a system with $n$ degrees of freedom necessarily have?

Comments on the questions:

3. Suppose by observations I found some conserved quantities, how can I be sure that I have found all the conserved quantities?
4. Is there any necessary upper bound?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/206355/50583 and its linked questions

Comment: Also possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/8626/2451 ,  https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/55861/2451 and links therein.